# Button Animation On Click And Go to Other Activity With An Other Animation

Tags: android

I need a code to do Button Animation On Click(like Rotation or quake or ..) And Go to Other Activity With An Other Animation After Button Animation Ended.
can you help me?

I tried this code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in);
            b.startAnimation(anim);
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
```

but both animation started same time

Comment: use pendingTransaction for activity animation...and for button animation load animation on button...

Comment: can you give me sample code please?

Comment: @RohitGoswami  Its better to post your answer here!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create animation file named shake.xml-

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    android:duration="70"
    android:fromDegrees="-5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toDegrees="5" />
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-10"
    android:toXDelta="10"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="70" />
</set>
```

Now in your main activity onCreate Block

```
b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startButtonAnimation(b);
        }
    });
```

after closing your onCreate() create method like this..

```
public void startButtonAnimation(Button btn){
    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
    btn.setAnimation(shake);
    btn.startAnimation(shake);

    shake.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    });
}
```

For more help let me know....

Answer (score 0):

Rohit is right.

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

from this link : http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-17%E2%80%93Animating-between-Activities

Comment: user is asking for the animating a button before moving to next screen

Comment: @Fahim: thanks for -1'd my answer!!!!!!!!!!! atleast its half true. Because of you expert guyz, newbie like me always afraids to answer. thanks for demoralizing us.

Comment: @EktaParikh you have only pasted want user have done in the question. -1 is for that. please check the question again. and u have not explained in your answer what exactly he has to do

Comment: @EktaParikh Will depend on you.. You can learn lots of things from it

Comment: @Fahim :  no man!! he tried my answer then edited his question. check edit time history.

Comment: ekta and nima both are new bie so both are in learning phase...so all the best..for more help add me on skype named peter rohit...

Answer (score 0):

Try in this manner. Move to next activity on animation finish

```
Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);

            }
        });
        b.startAnimation(anim);
```