# onClick change imageButton in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

When i click onClick button change imageButton in MainActivity.class

This is Activity with onClick button:

```
public void onClick8 (View view) {
    //here please code for change imagebutton from onClick
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(zem13.this, R.raw.melody);
    mediaPlayer.start();

}
```

This is code in MainActivity with imageButton:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.psik);
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935923/button-animation-on-click-and-go-to-other-activity-with-an-other-animation/28936798#28936798

Comment: There is something better please?

Comment: can you provide more code with explanation of what you want to do and exact question?

Comment: When i click on button in another activity it change imagebutton in MainActivity and I need a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand well, you should pass some indicator to change image resource to the MainActivity and set it in onCreate(). Try to change your code like this:

```
    public void onClick8 (View view) {
        //here please code for change imagebutton from onClick
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);

        myIntent.putExtra("shouldChangeButton", true);

        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(zem13.this, R.raw.melody);
        mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

and then in MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolean defaultValue = false; //or true as you need
        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("shouldChangeButton", defaultValue)) {
            ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
            ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
        }
    }
```

or in case you want permanent change, you should keep it in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) instead of passing it through intent:

```
public void onClick8 (View view) {
        //here please code for change imagebutton from onClick
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YourAppNamePrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("shouldChangeButton", true).apply();

        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(zem13.this, R.raw.melody);
        mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

and

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolean defaultValue = false; //or true as you need

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("YourAppNamePrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean shouldChangeButton = prefs.getBoolean("shouldChangeButton", defaultValue);

        if(shouldChangeButton) {
            ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
            ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much and how do I set it to last forever changed?

Comment: hope this is what you want. read doc about SharedPreferences. there is a link in the answer.

Comment: This only works on one ImageButton as I could do to make it work well for more imageButtons in MainActivity?

Comment: you have to set image resource to each button or to extend ImageButton class

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `onClickListener` to the view which would trigger `onClick`. And then you need override the `onClick` where you finish the operations to change `imageButton`.

Just Look at this:

```
        Button btn=new Button(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //to change you imageButton here.
            imageButton.setBackgroundResource(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @RohitGoswami, Could you cancel your looking down?